# How to build jar for Android library project in Intellij Idea without unnecessary content

Tags: android, ant, jar, library-project

When I build jar for Android library project in Intellij Idea it puts inside all dependent jar that I use in the project and *classes.jar*

[image]

but as I think all that stuff is unnecessary and jar can contain only compiled classes e.g.

[image]

Is that possible to compile *clean* jar in Idea? or should I use *ant* or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cloud compile the project using intelliJ, then locate the class files, the go to their root folder, then its parent folder and use `jar cvf foo.jar -R <root>/` in a shell.

Comment: It works, thanks!! But it will be better if process will be automated, e.g. using ant. Probably i should write ant script that compiles .java to .class files wit all dependencies, then put it into jar.

Comment: It can be done using ant jar target, the target supports a parameter to set the root of the files to add to the jars. So no need to cd, just use the ant jar task.

Comment: How to get structure of .class files like on second screenshot using ant? Probably that is plain _compile_ task?

Comment: try the jar task, you can definitely do that.